# Há crase em "Tudo aqui cheira a gasolina"?

Tags: crase

Chamamos de crase à junção da preposição "a" ao artigo definido "a" ou ao pronome demonstrativo "aquele/a, aqueles/as. A sua ocorrência é demonstrada pela presença do acento grave sobre a letra "a".

Na frase "Tudo aqui cheira a gasolina" há a necessidade do acento grave, ou seja, ocorre crase?

Comment: A pergunta soa tão absurdamente confusa se lida em Portugal... é que "**a** gasolina" [lê-se](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/) `/ä/` e "**à** gasolina" lê-se `/a/`. :) Enquanto no Brasil se leem as duas `/a/`.

Comment: @ANeves    Como pode a letra "a" soar "absurdamente confusa" aos ouvidos de alguém se ela não está sendo falada?  Exceto em livros didáticos, nenhum autor escreveria o "a" de "a gasolina" com símbolos fonéticos.  A pergunta é clara, há a necessidade do acento grave indicando a ocorrência de crase em "cheira a gasolina"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Crase é a junção da preposição “a” com o artigo definido “a(s)”, ou
>   ainda da preposição “a” com as iniciais dos pronomes demonstrativos
>   aquela(s), aquele(s), aquilo ou com o pronome relativo a qual (as
>   quais). Graficamente, a fusão das vogais “a” é representada por um
>   acento grave, assinalado no sentido contrário ao acento agudo: à.
>
> Como saber se devo empregar a crase? Uma dica é substituir o
>   substantivo  feminino por um masculino, se não houver a necessidade de
>   transformar "a" em "ao", não há a necessidade de crase .

*Exemplo: Tudo aqui cheira **a álcool***

Ou seja, se formos seguir esta dica, a frase "Tudo aqui cheira a gasolina" não possui crase

Comment: Seu exemplo poderia ser melhor.  "Tudo aqui cheira a álcool".  Não houve a necessidade de incluir o artigo definido "o", portanto a preposição está isolada.   Mas, se eu dissesse "tudo aqui está cheirando a gasolina que você derramou sobre a mesa" ?   O que vc me diz?

Comment: Nesse seu exemplo você não está usando a dica do texto, já que é obrigatório substituir o artigo "a" por "ao". Ai ficaria "Tudo aqui cheira ao álcool"... E desse jeito até parece certo.

Comment: Sim, neste caso há a necessidade de crase, porque a gasolina é específica.  Não é qualquer gasolina, é A gasolina que vc derramou.   Na verdade a dica funciona  melhor ao contrário do que vc escreveu: se substituirmos o substantivo feminino por um masculino e não houver a necessidade de transformar "a" em "ao", não há a necessidade de crase.  exemplos: Está cheirando a gasolina, está cheirando a álcool.  Está cheirando à gasolina que tu derramaste, está cheirando ao alcool que tu derramaste.   Nos dois primeiros exemplos não há a necessidade de crase,  Nos dois últimos há.

Comment: Se, substituindo um substantivo masculino tivermos que trocar "a" por "ao", é porque existe o artigo escondido na letra a, e portanto há a ocorrência de crase.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, vou alterar minha resposta...

Comment: Pronto, mas mesmo assim está correta, certo?